# How can I find the maximum curvature of $y = \ln x$?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Title says it all. I know that you can use the following equation to find curvature (kappa) for a parametric curve, $$\frac{\|r'(t) \times r''(t)\|}{\|r'(t)\|} $$ but I don't know how to do this for regular functions. Answer is at the point $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},\ln\big(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\big)\right)$.

Comment: Parametrise the curve as $(t,\log{t})$.

Comment: I added the "differential-geometry" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Comment: @FrenzyLi Yes, that looks like it

Comment: @RobertLewis Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found the formula. Whoops. For anyone who's looking, it's: $$ \kappa = \frac{f''(x)}{(1+(f'(x))^2)^{2/3}} $$